# Syncing iFrame with Textarea - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

CodeMirror is a software that basically just highlights the text you put in depending on the language and its very good to use!

How would I make a run button that makes it so when you click it, it takes the value of the textbox then puts it in an iFrame or something and puts it out.

For example if I put:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

It would actually output it on a different screen like this:

## Test

I guess a better way to put this is to sync an iFrame with a textarea.

I imagine you could use the onkeydown="function();" function and make it call the function, the function would then take the value of the textarea and then output it in an iFrame. Just not sure how to update iFrames with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use document.onkeydown, and sync the value of the textarea with your iframe.

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
      document.getElementById("myiframe").contentDocument.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("mytextarea").value;
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CCjb2/1/